# Unable to use Google maps API with VueJS / NuxtJS

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have search the internet in vain for a way to use Google Maps API with VueJS / NUxtJS.
I have seen many tutorial that show how it is done using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-api-loader) and even [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps).

However, despite following every single step as shown in the tutorial, I keep getting an error that looks something like this :

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <gmap-map> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Pages/googleMaps.vue> at pages/google-maps.vue
       <Nuxt>
         <Default> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5932
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
merged @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3301
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6405
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6405
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6405
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
mount @ client.js?06a0:689
mountApp$ @ client.js?06a0:727
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:62
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:296
prototype.<computed> @ runtime.js?96cf:114
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:62
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:152
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:162
Promise.then (async)
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:161
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:162
Promise.then (async)
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:161
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:195
callInvokeWithMethodAndArg @ runtime.js?96cf:194
enqueue @ runtime.js?96cf:217
prototype.<computed> @ runtime.js?96cf:114
runtime.async @ runtime.js?96cf:241
mountApp @ client.js?06a0:674
Promise.then (async)
eval @ client.js?06a0:88
eval @ client.js:1117
./.nuxt/client.js @ app.js:35
__webpack_require__ @ runtime.js:791
fn @ runtime.js:151
0 @ app.js:425
__webpack_require__ @ runtime.js:791
checkDeferredModules @ runtime.js:46
webpackJsonpCallback @ runtime.js:33
(anonymous) @ app.js:1
Show 38 more frames
2vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <gmap-marker> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Pages/googleMaps.vue> at pages/google-maps.vue
       <Nuxt>
         <Default> at layouts/default.vue
           <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5932
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
merged @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3301
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6405
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6405
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6372
hydrate @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6405
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6487
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4054
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
mount @ client.js?06a0:689
mountApp$ @ client.js?06a0:727
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:62
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:296
prototype.<computed> @ runtime.js?96cf:114
tryCatch @ runtime.js?96cf:62
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:152
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:162
Promise.then (async)
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:161
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:162
Promise.then (async)
invoke @ runtime.js?96cf:161
eval @ runtime.js?96cf:195
callInvokeWithMethodAndArg @ runtime.js?96cf:194
enqueue @ runtime.js?96cf:217
prototype.<computed> @ runtime.js?96cf:114
runtime.async @ runtime.js?96cf:241
mountApp @ client.js?06a0:674
Promise.then (async)
eval @ client.js?06a0:88
eval @ client.js:1117
./.nuxt/client.js @ app.js:35
__webpack_require__ @ runtime.js:791
fn @ runtime.js:151
0 @ app.js:425
__webpack_require__ @ runtime.js:791
checkDeferredModules @ runtime.js:46
webpackJsonpCallback @ runtime.js:33
(anonymous) @ app.js:1
Show 40 more frames
client.js?e0ba:95 [HMR] connected
```

I once got the map to be displayed using [vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) however I was unable to manipulate the map and the object `map` and `google` where undefined.

Some help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You might need to make sure it is only loaded and manipulated on the frontend (https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/)

Comment: @Sumurai8 could you please give me a code snippet I can try?

Comment: @EddyNtambwe Can you please provide a codesandbox or stackblitz with your code so that we can reproduce this error you're getting? Note that vue2-google-maps works without problem, e.g. see its example here http://xkjyeah.github.io/vue-google-maps/overlay.html